# How to add the variable to array and print it in index of array

Tags: objective-c

How to add the variable have sum is 42 to array and print it in index 42th of array. Thanks for helping. I do but can't add the variable to the number array and cant select 42th variable in the array

```
 static NSMutableArray * numberArray ;

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification
{
    int currentIndex;
    int sumOfDigits;
    numberArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (int i=69999;i<80000;i++)
    {
        sumOfDigits= [self findTotalNumber:i];

        if(sumOfDigits==42)
        {
            currentIndex++;
            [numberArray addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:i]];
        }

        if(currentIndex>=42)
            break;
    }

    NSLog(@"the number of elements in the array %lu",[numberArray count]);
}

-(void)print42thVariable
{
    NSInteger index=41;
    NSLog (@"42th variable of array is  = %@", [numberArray objectAtIndex:index]);
}

-(int)findTotalNumber:(int)number
{
    int digit,sum=0, temp;
    temp = number;
    while(temp > 0) 
    {
        digit = temp%10;
        sum += digit;
        temp = temp/10;
    }
    NSLog(@"Sum of digits of %i = %i",number,sum);
    return number;
}
```

Comment: What do you want? Don't quite understand your specification. You have already retrieved and printed the 42th element right?

Comment: I want find the 42th number which sum of its digits is 42.

Comment: Is my answer what you want?

Comment: Never ignore warnings. Fix the warnings and then update the code in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be trivial, you have written a `print42thVaribale` but you never call it. 
Call the method after Log??

```
   NSLog(@"the number of elements in the array %lu",[numberArray count]);
   [self print42thVariable];
```

There are some more corrections needed,

```
-(int)findTotalNumber:(int)number
{
    int digit,sum=0, temp;
    temp = number;
    while(temp > 0) 
   {
      digit = temp%10;
      sum += digit;
      temp = temp/10;
    }
    NSLog(@"Sum of digits of %i = %i",number,sum);
    return sum; //Needs to be sum and not number
}
```

This shouldn’t be an issue, but a good practise to initialize the variable.

```
int sumOfDigits = 0;
```

Comment: i try but have error 2014-06-03 03:34:03.172 IOSHieu[35304:303] *** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 41 beyond bounds for empty array

Comment: the number of elements in the array 0 and print42th not ru. i cant add the variable to the array

Comment: What is the output of this line? `NSLog(@"the number of elements in the array %lu",[numberArray count]);`

Comment: the return value has to be sum and not number. I ran the code and there seems like only 5 values in the specified range, 69999, 78999,79899, 79989 and 79998.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to find the 42th number whose sum of digits is 42, then you can just replace

```
NSLog(@"the number of elements in the array %lu",[numberArray count]);
```

with

```
NSLog(@"%i", [numberArray objectAtIndex:41])
```

This will print out the 42th element.